# Can not re-enable select tag after disabling JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using `change()` to enable or disable the select tag. I am able to disable the tag. But I can not seem to re-enable it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu-select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '2') {
      $('select').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('select').not(this).removeProp('disabled');

      $('select option').removeProp('disabled');

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="rating" class="form-control custom-select menu-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">

  <option value="">Select a Rating for the Movie/Series...</option>
  <option value="1" data-id="G">G</option>
  <option value="2" data-id="PG3">PG3</option>
  <option value="3" data-id="PG-13">PG-13</option>
  <option value="4" data-id="R">R</option>
  <option value="5" data-id="NC-17">NC-17</option>
  <option value="6" data-id="TV-14">TV-14</option>

</select>

<br><br>

<select name="rating" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">

  <option value="">Select a Rating for the Movie/Series...</option>
  <option value="1" data-id="G">G</option>
  <option value="2" data-id="PG3">PG3</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) on `.removeProp()`:

> The .removeProp() method removes properties set by the .prop() method.
>
> Note: **Do not** use this method to remove native properties such as checked, **disabled**, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Removing a property from a DOM element doesn't reset its state to how it was previously - many DOM property methods are *getter/setter* methods, so if the property is just removed, nothing may happen. You can see this more clearly in vanilla JS:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
select.disabled = true;
delete select.disabled;
```

```html
<select name="rating" class="form-control custom-select menu-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">

  <option value="">Select a Rating for the Movie/Series...</option>
  <option value="1" data-id="G">G</option>
  <option value="2" data-id="PG3">PG3</option>
  <option value="3" data-id="PG-13">PG-13</option>
  <option value="4" data-id="R">R</option>
  <option value="5" data-id="NC-17">NC-17</option>
  <option value="6" data-id="TV-14">TV-14</option>

</select>
```

So, the `else` block should just be:

```
$('select').not(this).prop('disabled', false);
```

```js
$('.menu-select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '2') {
    $('select').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('select').not(this).prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="rating" class="form-control custom-select menu-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">

  <option value="">Select a Rating for the Movie/Series...</option>
  <option value="1" data-id="G">G</option>
  <option value="2" data-id="PG3">PG3</option>
  <option value="3" data-id="PG-13">PG-13</option>
  <option value="4" data-id="R">R</option>
  <option value="5" data-id="NC-17">NC-17</option>
  <option value="6" data-id="TV-14">TV-14</option>

</select>

<br><br>

<select name="rating" class="form-control custom-select" style="width: 100%; height:36px;">

  <option value="">Select a Rating for the Movie/Series...</option>
  <option value="1" data-id="G">G</option>
  <option value="2" data-id="PG3">PG3</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry completely missed that.